# Changing Route Values in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to change my default route values.

Right now, I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I would like to have: `{controller}/{id}/{action}`

It is not as simple as changing the value as I have already tried this. How do I approach this?

Comment: Did you remove the 'optional' spec for `id` ?  There's a reason it is the last.

Comment: No. Is there a way to change the URL so `id` is not last, at least for some cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will  need 2 routes to accomplish this.

Just the rough idea, **untested**:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{id}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id=@"\d+" } // defaults
    );

 routes.MapRoute(
        "Shorter", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }         // defaults
    );
```

And do keep them in this order.

Not totally sure about the signature of the Actions, probably  `ActionResult Index(int? id)`

Comment: It works. However, there are some cases where the `id` signature of the actions is reading `0.` In these cases, it should just be `{controller}/{action}` but it is reading `{controller}/0/{action}`. Any ideas on this?

Comment: You can always handle that inside the Action method. It just doesn't fit the pattern(s).